# Android - App runs on install, crashes when it is re-opened

Tags: android, libgdx

When I first install the app onto my device, it works fine. Then, if I close it and re-open it, the app will crash with the below logcat message.

I don't think the first line regarding `libwvm.so` has anything to do with it, because that appears on install as well, but doesn't cause a crash.

I'm not sure what to do with this message, because as far as I can tell it doesn't point to anything in my code that I can try to fix.

I am following [this](http://www.kilobolt.com/day-12-completed-ui--source-code.html) tutorial to learn developing games with libGDX.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

```
02-13 11:01:59.292 13140-13156/? E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
02-13 11:02:01.317 13140-13154/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x76a96000 in tid 13154 (GLThread 823)
02-13 11:02:01.424 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-13 11:02:01.425 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/bullhead/bullhead:6.0.1/MMB29Q/2480792:user/release-keys'
02-13 11:02:01.426 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG: Revision: 'rev_1.0'
02-13 11:02:01.426 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
02-13 11:02:01.427 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG: pid: 13140, tid: 13154, name: GLThread 823  >>> com.mypackage.name <<<
02-13 11:02:01.427 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x76a96000
02-13 11:02:01.462 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG:     x0   00000000be39c000  x1   0000000076a96000  x2   00000000000000a0  x3   0000000000000120
02-13 11:02:01.463 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000000  x6   00000000be39c000  x7   0000000000000000
02-13 11:02:01.463 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000120  x11  0000000000000000
02-13 11:02:01.463 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000000000  x13  0000007f8b9ad468  x14  0000007f8b9ad458  x15  0000007f8b9ad4b8
02-13 11:02:01.464 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007f82329148  x17  0000007f900d4140  x18  0000000000000001  x19  0000000076a96120
02-13 11:02:01.464 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG:     x20  00000000be39c000  x21  0000000000000001  x22  0000000000000120  x23  0000000000000120
02-13 11:02:01.464 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000120  x25  0000000000000001  x26  0000000000000001  x27  0000000000000120
02-13 11:02:01.464 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000000076a96000  x29  0000007f8b9ace60  x30  0000007f81e57f74
02-13 11:02:01.464 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f8b9ace60  pc   0000007f900d4280  pstate 0000000020000000
02-13 11:02:01.468 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000001c280  /system/lib64/libc.so (memcpy+312)
02-13 11:02:01.469 3254-3254/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000025df70  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (BltDevice::ExecFastCopyBlock(void*, void const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, BltRect const*, BltRect const*, int)+144)
02-13 11:02:01.650 3254-3254/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
02-13 11:02:01.675 4413-13173/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 112)
02-13 11:02:01.682 366-366/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/13140/oom_score_adj; errno=22
02-13 11:02:06.360 3321-3321/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [LOWI-SERVER] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
02-13 11:02:32.344 6226-6226/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
02-13 11:02:32.344 6226-6226/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
02-13 11:02:32.945 7266-7266/? E/clatd: plat_prefix/dns(ipv4only.arpa) status = 7/No address associated with hostname
```

I don't think this is a logcat filtering issue. I selected "no filter" in the logcat and the message was the same, except for the last few lines which went like this instead of as above:

```
02-13 12:02:54.902 3254-3254/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
02-13 12:02:54.923 4413-17149/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 112)
02-13 12:02:54.928 4413-4459/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 60)
02-13 12:03:22.680 4413-5547/? E/native: do suspend true
02-13 12:03:22.688 6053-6302/? E/NxpTml: _i2c_write() errno : 5
02-13 12:03:22.688 6053-6302/? E/NxpTml: PN54X - Error in I2C Write.....
02-13 12:03:22.689 6053-6304/? E/NxpHal: write error status = 0x1ff
02-13 12:03:22.689 6053-6267/? E/NxpHal: write_unlocked failed - PN54X Maybe in Standby Mode - Retry
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.name.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the posted logcat that says anything about your app. Please continue to look through the logcat to find the error messages which are directly related to your own app.

Comment: Does this mean anything to you? `Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?`

Comment: Also, please post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I will post the manifest. This is all the shows in the logcat. After I close the app, I clear the logcat and open it again only for it to crash and this message to show up. There's nothing else in the logcat besides this.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? Which version? It sounds like Android Studio is filtering the logcat for you. Sometimes this is helpful, but in this case it is filtering out the important parts. You will need to figure out how to view **all** of the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most likely cause is that the OpenGL context is being released when the game goes into the background.

Lots of OpenGL based games use a class called glSurfaceView to manage the OpenGL surface, and by default, you get these sorts of crashes if you don't very carefully reinitialize all of your OpenGL objects after returning from suspend because they all get invalidated. In Ice Cream Sandwich, a function called setPreserveEGLContextOnPause was added to let you easily request that the OpenGL context is kept alive after your game goes into the background.

After some cursory research (so apologies if this is wrong) I believe libgdx uses it or something similar, but that it might be failing to work because you're not specifying a min or target sdk version in your manifest. Try adding a line like this to your manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19"  android:minSdkVersion="14" />
```

Documentation of the uses-sdk tag is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: I believe libgdx does call `setPreserveEGLContextOnPause` as seen [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidGraphics.java). The manifest line wasn't the problem, I just tested it. That line was originally removed because it's overriden by the gradle.